# How to write a java program to communicate with a exe application(written in .net) via entrypoint?

Tags: java, .net, exe

How to write a java program to communicate with a exe application(written in .net)  via entrypoint??

I am using process builder to invoke a exe file, The exe file has 2 entry points Initialize and TransactionProcess, I need to do a request/response(xml) using this entry points(similar to soap webservice but not a web service), Let me know how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can execute an executable file using this code

```
Runtime.getRuntime(pathToExecutableFile);
```

Comment: Thanks aptuv, This can execute the file, but how can access the entry points, without starting the application.